# Custom Rails Actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a cusotm actions in rails. I though it would of work but for some reason it doesn't see the action has show. I remember seing somewhere I might have to set something but I can't remember.

Here my route files

```
  resources :friends do
    collection do
      delete 'cancel'
    end
  end
```

In my rake route this generate the following

```
cancel_api_v1_friends DELETE /api/v1/friends/cancel(.:format)                           api/v1/friends#cancel
```

So when i go to ...api/v1/friends/cancel.json to see the api created by it say can't find show actions.

Is there something i missed?

This is the error I get

```
The action 'show' could not be found for Api::V1::FriendsController
```

My controller has the following method

```
def cancel
  ...
end
```

Comment: See my answer. It may help you. Just go through http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. change your route like

```
  resources :friends do
    member do
      delete :cancel
    end
  end
```

You can call this method by

```
cancel_friend_path(friend_object)
```

And write a method in FriendsController

```
def cancel
  whatever you wanna do.
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're hitting /api/v1/friends/cancel.json in a browser, it'll be doing a GET not a DELETE and calling the show method with the ID of 'cancel'

To test this properly, use something like curl.

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/v1/friends/cancel.json
```

Matta

Comment: But what if in the future I want to create a Show method, would my Cancel and Show method conflict?

Comment: Nope.  it's the "DELETE" http method the decides what rails method gets called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RESTClient to test this.

Here is an amazing [FireFox RESTClient Add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/restclient/).

With this addons you are able to request with GET,PUT, POST, DELETE ... etc methods.

Actually you need to request DELETE not GET as Matt answered previously. Hitting `api/v1/friends/cancel.json` you requesting GET method.